# Elements gets out of window area

Tags: css, window

menu links get out of the window area? Why does it happen? Why can't I scroll up to the first menu on mobile screens? What's wrong with my code?

Here I want to make a fullscreen popup menu, that is why .menu is fixed, and I want to center all links as well. But I can't seem to get some menu links on smaller devices. How can I leave .menu fixed and center all links?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQVT.png)

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: #05b5f9; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: relative; */
  overflow: auto;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #05b5f9;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #05b5f9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu5</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu6</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu7</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set a fixed height for your `.menu` which in combination with `display: fixed` won't let you scroll.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  /* background: #05b5f9; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: relative; */
  overflow: auto;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #05b5f9;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #05b5f9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu5</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu6</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu7</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="link">Menu8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That you are currently just able to scroll a little bit is the result of `overflow: auto;` on your `.list`

Comment: Here I want to make fullscreen popup menu, which is why .menu is fixed, and I want to center all link as well. But I can't seem to get some menu links on smaller devices. How can I leave .menu fixed and center all links? Is it possible to center links with flex and leave .menu fixed?

Comment: @Jack Why can't you use `position: absolute` for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is in your `.menu` class. Since the menu class element goes inside the document element, the `height: 100%;` will take the height of the parent, i.e. the document, i.e. the entire viewport height.

I don't see any problem while running your code in a separate window. [This is what I see while running your code in full screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9RZQ.png) I am guessing that the problem arises when you have something displaying over the menu element, because the `top: 0;` will make sure the the menu element starts from the top of the screen.

If you can share the full code, maybe we can help better. Cheerio!

Comment: op is talking about mobile. The problem will only occur if not enough screen space is available.